# Starting supervisorctl gives ERROR (spawn error) on laravel queue worker process

Tags: linux, multithreading, ubuntu, supervisord

So i have installed supervisor and it appears to be running. 
I have placed my config file for the queue worker in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf

And it looks like this

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=2 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=4
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

And my supervisord.conf looks like this

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0775                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)
chown=root

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
 ; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
 [rpcinterface:supervisor]
 supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

I am getting the error -  ERROR (spawn error) when i attempt to start the processes.

When i look at the log file it shows -

```
2017-05-28 22:21:20,697 INFO exited: laravel-worker_01 (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-28 22:21:20,702 INFO exited: laravel-worker_00 (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-28 22:21:20,704 INFO exited: laravel-worker_02 (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-28 22:21:20,706 INFO exited: laravel-worker_03 (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-28 22:21:23,711 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_00' with pid 16280
2017-05-28 22:21:23,713 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_01' with pid 16281
2017-05-28 22:21:23,715 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_02' with pid 16282
2017-05-28 22:21:23,719 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_03' with pid 16283
2017-05-28 22:21:23,772 INFO exited: laravel-worker_02 (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-28 22:21:23,774 INFO gave up: laravel-worker_02 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2017-05-28 22:21:23,774 INFO exited: laravel-worker_01 (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-28 22:21:23,776 INFO gave up: laravel-worker_01 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2017-05-28 22:21:23,776 INFO exited: laravel-worker_03 (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-28 22:21:23,777 INFO gave up: laravel-worker_03 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2017-05-28 22:21:23,777 INFO exited: laravel-worker_00 (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-28 22:21:24,778 INFO gave up: laravel-worker_00 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

I have verified that all the files in my config file exist. I am not sure i am using the right configuration in my laravel-worker.conf. I have searched documentation and other stackoverflow threads but could not find the solution

Comment: as a quick way to troubleshoot, you can run the command value in your `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf` file on cli, it would most likely tell you the source of the spawn error. The command value in this case is `php /var/www/html queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=2 --daemon`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So the problem apparently was with my laravel-worker
I needed to complete command path by adding '/artisan' to the path like so -

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=2 --daemon
```

Answer (score 22):

I got resolve by restarting supervisor

```
sudo service supervisor reload
```

Answer (score 5):

The same issue I was also facing, after specifying the queue name properly issue resolved

```
command=php /home/vagrant/code/prject1/artisan queue:work redis --queue=email --sleep=3 --tries=1 --daemon
```

Here is my worker file [laravel-worker.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Xzy.png)

[execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFgjA.png)

Answer (score 1):

you need add artisan in your conf and add user in your conf file

for example

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/site.com/kernel/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 -- 
tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=10
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/site.com/kernel/worker.log
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 7 or below you can encounter errors if options are passed within the command. In my case, removing these options fixed the issue.

Change this line:

`command=php /var/www/html queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=2 --daemon`

To this:

`command=php /var/www/html queue:work`

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the type of error your getting by looking at your log file
`stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when having a bug from a config file in `/config` folder.

Answer (score 0):

or if `service supervisor reload` didn't worked you can use `service supervisor restart`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34576181)